# How to use a WinAPI struct in UASM without writing it and its members

Tags: assembly, winapi, struct, extern, masm64

UASM (a MASM clone) 64 bit Visual Studio 2022 solution with ICC.
I want to use the CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO struct that is defined in the WinAPI.
I know how to use it by copying its declaration from the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-cursor-info-str).

This is a partial UASM program without the main function and it works.

```
.CODE
USE64
INCLUDELIB Kernel32.lib

EXTERNDEF __imp_SetConsoleCursorInfo :QWORD

.CONST
ALIGN 4
    ; Cursor size.
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO STRUCT
        dwSize DWORD 100 ; Fully filled.
        bVisible BOOL 1 ; Visible. BOOL is defined as DWORD in another file.
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO ENDS

.DATA
ALIGN 4
    MyCursorD CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO {}

.CODE
        mov rcx, rax ; rax already have handle from GetStdHandle of STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE.
        lea rdx, MyCursorD ; *lpConsoleCursorInfo.
        call __imp_SetConsoleCursorInfo
```

How can I access the WinAPI CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO struct without explicitly copying it and its members to my program the same way I used EXTERNDEF to access the WinAPI function?
Is there an EXTERN or EXTERNDEF that I can use?

I tried many combinations of EXTERN and EXTERNDEF and even tried Windows 11 Copilot.
It always failed with a syntax error of MyCursorD.

Since the struct is defined in the .CONST section and already has the values I need, is there a way to use it as const without creating the MyCursorD variable in the .DATA section?

Comment: `EXTERNDEF` is a directive to the linker to help it resolve the symbol. It does nothing to tell the assembler what `__imp_SetConsoleCursorInfo` is. Indeed, you told it yourself `: QWORD`. Structures do not have linkage, so there is nothing to `EXTERN`. Even if there were, it wouldn't help, since `EXTERN` is an instruction to the linker, not the assembler. You'll have to do what you did: Define the struct yourself via `CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO STRUCT`. Not clear how `MyCursorD` enters the picture.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, now it makes much more sense. The MyCursorD is in the .data section, so it is the object I interact with. Every trick I tried to use the struct as a const, failed... if there is a way, please enlighten me. –

Comment: If you want it to be const, then put it in the .const segment.